# Is there a way to confiture the first cursor position of jsdoc generated by vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As the vidio in [VS code's JS Doc support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_js-doc-support) page shows, when I enter /** to a function with parameters, the cursor will jump to the first parameter's doc place. But I want to write the description of the function first, which means I want the cursor to jump to the first line of the whole jsdoc instead of the first  line of the parameter.

How can I do this?